# Redux store is lost in next route on replace() inside onEnter

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux, isomorphic

So, similar to the code in `router.js`, in the boilerplate at https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/ `master branch`

```
const requireLogin = (nextState, replace, cb) => {

    if(!isLoggedIn) {
        store.dispatch(getUserInfo(somePayLoad)).then(checkLoginStatus);
    }
    function checkLoginStatus() {
        const {authorization: { user }} = store.getState();
        if(!user.typeA) {
            replace('/home');
        }
        cb();
    }
}
```

So, when I `replace()`, and if the if condition `!user.typeA` fails, then it goes to the usual called route, access the user details that were fetched as in above code and also, I can easily call `logout` dispatcher I wrote whenever user wants to exit. But when if condition is passed, it replaces to `/home` page and opens(redirects) to home page successfully. But I can no longer have user details in `authorization` store. Neither I can call `logout` dispatcher.

**Note:**

```
  if(!user.typeA) {
      const path = '/home';
      const query = {error:'anything'};
      const state = store.getState();
      replace({ path, query, state });
  }
```

instead of

```
  if(!user.typeA) {
      replace('/home')
  }
```

also doesn't work.

How to achieve this?